Definition of ECL50 coordinate frame?
Is there a document with the definition of the "ECL50" frame? It was used at least in the Voyager and Ulysses missions. I have seen in literature people saying "ECL50 is the same as ECLIPB1950", but is there the original document with the definition of the ECL50 frame somewhere?

I am unsure if the original definition is really anywhere easy to find, but I found this documentation from Galileo:

Ecliptic Epoch of 1950 (ECL50 Coordinate System). The plane of the ecliptic is chosen as the primary reference plane of this coordinate system. (See Figure 13.) As the origin for one coordinate, the ecliptic longitude λ, the vernal point for the Epoch of 1950 is chosen and refers to the beginning of the Besselian year and corresponds to the Julian Ephemeris date 24 33282.423357. The ecliptic longitude is measured from it (in the same direction as the apparent annual solar motion) to the point of intersection of the longitude circle of the object with the ecliptic. The longitude circles, or closures are the great circles perpendicular to the ecliptic and, therefore, passing through the poles of the ecliptic.
The values are stated in degrees from 0 to 360 deg with 0 starting at the vernal point and increasing in value clockwise when looking at the ecliptic north pole Ep. The other coordinate, the ecliptic latitude β, is measured from the ecliptic along the closure of the celestial object in degrees, positive in the direction toward the ecliptic north pole and negative toward the south pole.

From Galileo Flight Orbiter Equipment Configuration, Page 36 and Page 37.
Figure 13, from page 40:


Thanks for the link.

I think that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for the answer!

@ThePuzzlemaker I'd like to acknowledge you in my work. If you'd like to be acknowledged could you reach out to me at george.xystouris@gmail.com ?
